# i18next - Global default value

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I'm using i18next (along with 'react-i18next') in a react-native project.

Everything is working as expected apart from one thing:

When the app initially loads I see a flash of the `key` value (e.g. `home.title`) before the translation file is loaded. As soon as the translations file loads this is replaced with the expected value.

I want to display nothing ('') in this case until the value loads.

I know I can set a default value on a per key basis like `t('home.title', '')` or `t('home.title', { defaultValue: '' })` but this will be quite painful now .

My question is - can I set a default value on a global level (perhaps in the `init` of i18n)?

Answer (score 0):

No, the correct way would be to make use of Suspense or check the ready flag: https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#not-using-suspense